# Copy Constructor C++ compilation error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, copy-constructor

I am a beginner in C++ and particularly data structures. This project we are working with truncated series (something like that). I get this weird compilation error and I am not sure what it is telling me. The program was running fine before I created the copy constructor so that might be the culprit. I was having a hard time making one, but I am not sure if that is how I am supposed to.

The error looks sorta like this:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ostream:1077:1: note: 
      candidate template ignored: could not match
      'basic_string<type-parameter-0-0, type-parameter-0-1, type-parameter-0-2>'
      against 'Series'
operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os,
^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ostream:1094:1: note: 
      candidate template ignored: could not match
      'shared_ptr<type-parameter-0-2>' against 'Series'
operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os, shared_ptr<_Yp> const& __p)
^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/ostream:1101:1: note: 
      candidate template ignored: could not match 'bitset<_Size>' against
      'Series'
operator<<(basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& __os, const bitset<_Size>& __x)
```

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Series {
    private:
            size_t degree;
            vector <double> coefs;

    public:
            Series():degree(0){ }

            Series(size_t d): degree(d){
                    for(int i = 0; i < (degree+1); i++){
                            coefs.push_back(0.0);
                    }
            }

            Series(double term){
                    coefs[0] = term;
            }

            Series(size_t d2,vector <double> newcoeffs): Series(d2) {
                            for (int i = 1; i < (d2+1); i++) {
                                    coefs.at(i) = newcoeffs.at(i-1);
                             }
            }

            Series(const Series & rhs) {
                            degree = rhs.degree;
                            vector <double> coefs;
                            for (int i = 1; i < (degree+1); i++) {
                                    coefs.at(i) = rhs.coefs.at(i);
                            }
            }    

            ~Series() {
                    coefs.clear();
            }

            void print(ostream & out) const{
                    if (degree == 0) {
                            return;
                    }
                    for (int i = 1; i < degree+1; i++)
                            out << coefs[i] << "x^" << i << " + ";
                    out << coefs[0];
            }

};
ostream & operator <<(ostream & out, const Series & s){
                    s.print(out);
                    return out;
}

int main(){
    vector <double> v {2.1,3.5,6.2};
    vector <double> z {1.1,2.3,4.0};
    Series two(3,z);
    Series one(two);

    cout << one << end;
    cout << two << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `coefs.at(i) = rhs.coefs.at(i);` will likely lead to a segmentation fault, as your container has not been initialized before.

Comment: I think you have to declare your << operator a friend operator, and define it outside the class.

Comment: @informaticienzero I am getting this now : libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: vector
Abort trap: 6, does this have anything to do with that? how do I fix it?

Comment: @SuzanneElm Of course you get such an exception. In C++, `at` is a function accessing elements of a `std::vector` but there, your's is empty. To add values inside, you need to use `push_back`.

Answer (score 3):

It's just a typo in your `main`

```
cout << one << end;
```

should be

```
cout << one << endl;
```

The unhelpful error message you got was because [`end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) is the name of a function that already exists in the `std` namespace. This is a good example of why `using namespace std;` is often [advised against](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Idk how I overlooked that

Answer (score 0):

Not directly related to your problem, but your code will lead to a `std::out_of_range` exception. This is because you use `at`, whish is a function accessing a value inside a `std::vector`, not adding values in it.

```
for (int i = 1; i < (degree+1); i++)
    // SEGFAULT !
    coefs.at(i) = rhs.coefs.at(i);
```

You have to use `std::vector::push_back` to add elements in your container.

```
for (int i = 1; i < (degree+1); i++)
    coefs.push_back(rhs.coefs.at(i));
```

Or even shorter with modern C++ :

```
for (auto elem : rhs)
    coefs.push_back(elem);
```

Comment: there will be no segmentation fault because `at` checks the range and throws `std::out_of_range`

Comment: @bolov True. I never use `at`, always `[]`, that's why I forgot about this.